# How to create private discord channel using DSharpPlus?

Tags: c#, discord, bots, dsharp+

I am trying to make a bot command to create a private channel, however, when I call it nothing happens even though the bot has full Administrator permissions granted.

Here is the command:

````
   ```[Command("makeprivate")]
    public async Task MakePrivate(CommandContext ctx, string name)
    {
        await ctx.Guild.CreateChannelAsync( name, ChannelType.Private ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }```
````